# Msnmsgr.exe - No Disk in the Drive

Tags: windows-7

Running Windows 7 beta, I occasionally get a popup from msnmsgr.exe claiming "There is no disk in the drive.  Please insert a disk into drive D:".

There are a few suggestions on the 'net about it, mostly involving uninstalling and reinstalling Windows Messenger (not something I put a lot of confidence in), or stuff related to Sony Vaios (which I don't have).

Anyone got a solution that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reinstall WLM first before everything else. Don't be scared about it.

When it ask for disk, have you details about the file he requesting? Usely it's written in the text over the path field.

Comment: No filename is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This [forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/37f614f0-2520-4a96-9510-e7d9941275ea/) contains **a** solution:

> The company I am working for is a
>   system builder
>
> As such, it has copies of Windows 7 on
>   disk - one of which I used to install
>   the trial
>
> Remember when Messenger first appeared
>   - it was one of the 'Windows Services' things that you installed on a
>   separate tab in the Add/Remove
>   programs part of Control Panel ?
>
> Seems that if you install from a disk
>   (or the copy you have used was - at
>   some point in time) created to be
>   installed from a disk...
>
> ...then you need to put that disk in
>   to the system in order to complete the
>   Messenger installation

Comment: I installed Messenger as part of Windows Live Essentials, which I downloaded and installed off my system drive, so this isn't relevant.  Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/w7itproappcompat/thread/c765c456-f78c-45b7-a37e-d5482f5190dc) has the solution to your problem.